# Different options for test on a multiproject Scala SBT using ThisBuild

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an SBT project with 2 subprojects and I want to have test compiler settings different from the normal compiler settings, for all the subprojects. I.e. I want to enforce `-Xfatal-warnings` for the main code but not for tests.

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve setting each subproject individuall but all at once.

I'm working with SBT 1.3.9 and Scala 2.13.3

This is a sample of what I have in SBT:

```scala
lazy val root: Project = project
  .in(file("."))
  .aggregate(projectA, projectB)

lazy val projectA: Project = project
  .in(file("projectA"))
  .settings(
    name := "projectA",
  )

lazy val projectB: Project = project
  .in(file("projectA"))
  .settings(
    name := "projectA",
  )
```

I tried plenty of options but I can't set test options different to compile options.
As a quick summary, I tried to play around with scoping:

- `scalacOptions := Seq(XXX)` + `Test/scalacOptions := Seq(YYY)`
- `Compile/scalacOptions := Seq(XXX)` + `Test/scalacOptions := Seq(YYY)`
- `ThisBuild/scalacOptions := Seq(XXX)` + `ThisBuild/Test/scalacOptions := Seq(YYY)`
- `ThisBuild/Compile/scalacOptions := Seq(XXX)` + `ThisBuild/Test/scalacOptions := Seq(YYY)`
- Also tried to scope under `test` and played around with various combinations of the above.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630465/sbt-set-specific-scalacoptions-options-when-compiling-tests) is the closest to what I need but it doesn't work, probably beucase it's not meant for multiproject files.

**UPDATE:**

I've just discovered that if I scope the setting to a specific project then I have the behaviour I want:

```scala
projectA / Compile / scalacOptions := Seq(XXX)
projectA / Test / scalacOptions := Seq(YYY)
projectB / Compile / scalacOptions := Seq(XXX)
projectB / Test / scalacOptions := Seq(YYY)
```

but if I use `ThisBuild` it doesn't work

```scala
ThisBuild / Compile / scalacOptions := Seq(XXX)
ThisBuild / Test / scalacOptions := Seq(XXX)
```

Do I have a wrong understanding of something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThisBuild` scope axis value is often misunderstood when attempting to define common settings for multiple subprojects. Please note it does [**not**](https://gitter.im/sbt/sbt?at=5ce6ca29ad024978c6176238) mean

> add this common setting to all the subprojects in this build

Instead the meaning is closer to

> If a subproject does not define this setting, then, possibly, delegate (fall back) to `ThisBuild`

For example, executing `inspect Test / scalacOptions` on basic hello world project gives

```
...
[info] Provided by:
[info]  ProjectRef(uri("file:/my/Path/To/Project/"), "root") / Test / scalacOptions
...
[info] Delegates:
[info]  Test / scalacOptions
[info]  Runtime / scalacOptions
[info]  Compile / scalacOptions
[info]  scalacOptions
[info]  ThisBuild / Test / scalacOptions
[info]  ThisBuild / Runtime / scalacOptions
[info]  ThisBuild / Compile / scalacOptions
[info]  ThisBuild / scalacOptions
[info]  Zero / Test / scalacOptions
[info]  Zero / Runtime / scalacOptions
[info]  Zero / Compile / scalacOptions
[info]  Global / scalacOptions
...
```

The `Provided by` section shows the scope with highest precedence

```
ProjectRef(uri("file:/my/Path/To/Project/"), "root") / Test / scalacOptions
```

then `Delegates` section shows the remainder of precedence order where we notice there are bunch of scopes "above" the ones using `ThisBuild` as project axis. Therefore because of how sbt scope delegation [rules](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Scope-Delegation.html#Rule+4%3A+The+subproject+axis+search+path) work

```
ThisBuild / Test / scalacOptions
```

does not mean tests within subprojects will automatically pick up the new value as it is quite low in the picking order.

I believe the most straightforward approach around sbt's arguably confusing scoping rules is to define a `val` with common settings and then simply add that value to each subproject, or define an [auto plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2899#issuecomment-271450813)

> Auto plugins can inject project settings across the board

Consider my related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62113907/5205022) which demonstrates the two approaches.

Comment: I knew all this stuff and yet I couldn't put things together. SBT is complex. I really dislike using a common setting `val`, I'm trying with an autoplugin as I have already defined a few